# Typescript generic type - Type 'keyof T1' cannot be used to index type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have functions to validate forms, I want the function to be in a separate file, but I have a type problem for `validationRequirements[fieldName]` i getting error `Type 'keyof T1' cannot be used to index type '{ name: (value: string) => boolean; }'.`

Here is my validations requirements:

```
const validationRequirements = {
    name: (value: string) => false, //mock
}
```

Interface for createValidationObj:

```
interface CreateValidationObjI<T1> {
    validation: T1
    fieldName: keyof T1
    value: string
}
```

Here I call a function to update the validation object, I pass `validationI` as typescript argument then i use it as generic:

```
const onChangeValidation = ({ value, fieldName }: { value: string; fieldName: keyof typeof validation }) => {
    const validationObj = createValidationObj<validationI>({ validation, fieldName, value })
}
```

Here is the validation function, I want that function in separate:

```
const createValidationObj = <T1 extends {}>({ validation, fieldName, value }: CreateValidationObjI<T1>) => ({
    ...validation,
    [fieldName]: {
        ...validation[fieldName],
        isValid: validationRequirements[fieldName](value), <-- Type 'keyof T1' cannot be used to index type '{ name: (value: string) => boolean; }'.
        isTouched: true,
    },
})
```

Link to example: [Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=38&ssc=2&pln=36&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgG5wDbACZzMAexAElkBvAKGWuRDgFsIAucqm94AZwDVMcWARgQIYIcEG3bUuAFQIBXBAAsI2QcNHjJU6FAJQAspwDmLTmCihj2gL4AaCjYoUERc2j658RFuixfCEmQAXlZ2OkYWSikaLl5-FngMTggHGOlOOUUVNWQklLT03X0jU2QAIgNQZABmZGU4KE5ywup7R2dXEHc-HDxAgCUIAEd5YCgIRnBOELCaCOZkAAo-eUXzSxBjAEoQgD48zALkAHoT+gIEAGsOilBIWEQUAGEJvAh4vu8QAHkBACtiAAeGQARgO0RovQCPmQYO0MGAEAw2AAcgxFlcIABPAgwOGg7SrdYWKy3LruBBvSCfGG-AGzEGg5AQAAekBA2BmZBseyWZA8-n6RDseSRKPRjFFxOQNhYrzENM8wvpgKZe12wQO-O0ADp9dCVa1kABtRHItEYgC6UW07H1usN3zN4stjCtxo4PE8vmV3yGo3Gkwg0xdFslECtK0wa22ntimQUylULAsa2N7Rs206bjAyCIzyU4mMHz9gVm-MF6bF4YxsqiVZJm2MAG4axKMSwsbj8WBsQAHCB4wVfctZ-ZzagUvNOwJ-f6zKmK0tC77zoGzojEPkCzcgUXmjtSxuy7M2IA)

Comment: Is it intentional that `T1` extends `{}` rather than the referenced `validationRequirements`?

Comment: Even if `T1` extends the interface `validationI`, the code will not work because that implies `T1` may have some extra keys different from `validationI`. Either `T1` must have same or lesser(subset) keys than `validationI` or assigning might have reverse (but it is not the requirement of the code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

Consider this code. Any field from object of type `Parent` is assignable to object of type `Child` (as soon as their type matches). This is because `Parent` has keys `"a" | "b"`. So, definitely, `parentObject` has keys that `childObject` has but vice-versa is not true as `parentObject` is missing key `c` from the `childObject`.

**So, in short, the keys of the object whose fields we are assigning must be subset of keys the object to which we are assigning.**

The keys of type `{}` is an empty set, therefore, the error in function `f3`.

```js
interface Parent {
    a: string
    b: string
}

interface Child {
    a: string
    b: string
    c: string
}

const parentObject: Parent = {
    a: "abc",
    b: "string"
}

const childObject: Child = {
    a: "abc",
    b: "string",
    c: "string"
}

type KeysOfParent = keyof Parent // "a" | "b"
type KeysOfChild = keyof Child // "a" | "b" | "c"

function f(field: keyof Parent) {
    childObject[field] = "abc" // OK
}

function f2(field: keyof Child) {
    parentObject[field] = "abc" // ERROR
}

function f3<T extends {}>(field: keyof T) {
    parentObject[field] = "abc" // ERROR
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=36&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApyhcyDeAoZQ5OALmQGcwpQBzAogIzMupDoF889RJZEUAwgAtgAGwAmueoVIUqtaciZzWdIsgTN5bPJzwIA9iErIADhixgA8gwBWEBGDLpM2ALxT1sgERwGCbwAaRWVvFlpvXS5DYzANEQkbe0cyYTFJD3wvMl9-IJCc8LZ89U1kMO0aSL0wAE9TFABpCFryKxgXS2QPAGsWgxg0C2wAehHyuG9kAB9yhki6huRm1va0iW7kPtqB5HXJMYmp2e95mfKArhgAVxBHYCNkGAAKGGAICTJt3c7wAEpPEQEAlxEkHGAANpvD7iAC6m1yAWQhysjSieBudzADxATwATK93p8tv1BvsAVkiOZXNY7OCoUS4Qi-EjDgBRABKHKsHPRmPujxgAGYADwAFWQEAAHpAQOJyLh2AA+Qkwr6k5BiimKamWMGOBkw+EeRFTdlcnm6IA)

So, in the question, in function `createValidationObj`, `fieldName` has keys - `keyof {}` which is definitely not asubset of keys of `validationRequirements` ("name"). So the error.

### Solution

If it does not violate your requirements, remove `T1` at all.

```js
interface validationI {
    name: {
        isValid: boolean
        isTouched: boolean
        errorMsg: string
    },
    field2: {
        isValid: boolean
        isTouched: boolean
        errorMsg: string
    },
}

const validation: validationI = {
    name: {
        isValid: false,
        isTouched: false,
        errorMsg: "Min 3 chars",
    },
    field2: {
        isValid: false,
        isTouched: false,
        errorMsg: "Min 3 chars",
    },
}
type X = keyof typeof validation

const validationRequirements = {
    name: (value: string) => false, //mock
    field2: (value: string) => false, //mock
}

interface CreateValidationObjI<T1 extends validationI> {
    validation: T1
    fieldName: keyof T1
    value: string
}

const createValidationObj = ({validation, fieldName, value}: CreateValidationObjI<validationI>) => ({
    ...validation,
    [fieldName]: {
        ...validation[fieldName],
        isValid: validationRequirements[fieldName](value),
        isTouched: true,
    }
})

const onChangeValidation = ({ value, fieldName }: { value: string; fieldName: keyof typeof validation }) => {
    const validationObj = createValidationObj({ validation, fieldName, value })
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=50&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgG5wDbACZzMAexAElkBvAKGWuRDgFsIAucqm94AZwDVMcWARgQIYIcEG3bUuAFQIBXBAAsI2QcNHjJU6FAJQAspwDmLTmCihj2gL4AabTGAQM2AEwtKUml15Y1yEIiYhLe0pxyiioBQZqhYbr6RqbI5pYg1uz2FDYUFAhE5mh8uPhELOj+eIQkyAC8rOx0jJ7aHDwlLPAYnBAOYciyCsqqXZi9-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)